# Is it possible to monitor Spring Batch job execution status using Spring Boot Admin tool?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-boot-admin

I am working on a Spring Batch application (based on Spring Boot). In order to monitor it I installed the **Spring Boot Admin** tool: https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.4.3/

It provides a lot of information related Spring Boot but I can't understand if it also can provide me information about of the execution status of my Spring Batch Jobs. For example if a specific job complete with success or failed.

Is it possible monitor these information with the Spring Boot Admin tool? In case it is possible, how can I check my jobs status?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check the status, particularly of your spring batches whether it is failed or successful.

If you are deploying Spring Batch Admin as a WAR file (either the sample or one you rolled yourself), just deploy it as normal to a servlet container.

Refer to Spring documentation for
[Spring Batch Admin User Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/trunk/reference/reference.xhtml)

**UPDATE**

Please refer to this webpage it will give exact idea and solution for your problem.

[Monitoring Jobs](https://livebook.manning.com/book/spring-batch-in-action/chapter-12/)